# Hyper-V (Win10) creating branching checkpoint tree

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10

I have seen screen grabs showing Checkpoints that branch such as this article on Veemam.  However I seem to be overlooking how to create these branches.  These would be really useful in my workflow.

https://www.veeam.com/blog/what-are-hyper-v-snapshots-12-things-to-know.html

[Checkpoint Tree Branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Dl8.png)

Thank you!
Kelly

Answer (score 1):

A tree indicates the VM was restored, reverted to a previous checkpoint. Future checkpoints start a new node with a new delta. Look at the time stamps in that screenshot.

Trees of checkpoints are not a long term solution. The accumulated deltas consume storage space and performance. To store a point in time for more than a couple days, use a backup system.